# Arango AQL use index to search for existing property

Tags: arangodb, aql

I want to get all object with available property "available"

```
For u in col
filter u.available!= null
return u
```

But the above query would not use index even if u.available is indexed. How can I iterate with the use of index?

Comment: Can you share your index definitions and the explain output? FWIW: if you don't care about documents where this field is null or not available, I would recommend to use a sparse index.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With comment from @mpoeter , I can create an index that are specifically spare to force arango to use index.

Comment: Could you show an example of the code?